# Running ProGuard to Generate Signed APK

Tags: gradle, proguard

I have enabled pro guard in my gradle and trying to generate a signed APK with V1 and V2 signatures switched on. The problem however is that it fails giving me more than 100 lines of

`duplicate definition of library class
can't find dynamically referenced class
can't find referenced class` etc

I have added a few of these errors below.

**Gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.example.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}
```

**Error**

```
Note: duplicate definition of library class [okhttp3.Address]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [okhttp3.Authenticator$1]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [okhttp3.Authenticator]

Note: duplicate definition of library class [okio.AsyncTimeout$1]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [okio.AsyncTimeout$2]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog]


Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl


Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzbr: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.io.Memory
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzbr: can't find dynamically referenced class org.robolectric.Robolectric
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzcn: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzco: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.Extension
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzcr: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionSchemaFull
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzdw: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.DescriptorMessageInfoFactory
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzee: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.MapFieldSchemaFull


Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor { okhttp3.Response intercept(okhttp3.Interceptor$Chain); }', but not the descriptor class 'okhttp3.Interceptor$Chain'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor$ForwardingResponseBody { StethoInterceptor$ForwardingResponseBody(okhttp3.ResponseBody,java.io.InputStream); }', but not the descriptor class 'okhttp3.ResponseBody'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor$OkHttpInspectorRequest { StethoInterceptor$OkHttpInspectorRequest(java.lang.String,okhttp3.Request,com.facebook.stetho.inspector.network.RequestBodyHelper); }', but not the descriptor class 'okhttp3.Request'
```

Comment: Any updates? I see similar warnings from ProGuard.